# XLR to headphone “jack”?

Tags: recording, homerecording, headphones

I want to practice performing at home. Shure X2U offers this little attachment that enables headphone monitoring that goes anywhere with the microphone itself, instead of being always tied near the computer. Are there any alternatives to this that are, hopefully, a bit smaller?

Comment: That sounds like a request for recommendations for specific equipment, which is against the rules here

Comment: @DaveJacoby That was my initial reaction as well, but I think it's useful as a request for types of alternatives rather than a specific item.

Comment: How much smaller to you want? It’s only about 5 inches long. Behringer makes 2 similar products that are less expensive that you can search for, the  P2 and the PM1.